# How to register an icon in FluentUI from an external SVG?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm trying to register an SVG as an icon, in Fluent UI.

If the SVG exists in the local, referencing it directly like so:

```js
registerIcons({
   icons: {
       'icon-name': <svg></svg>
   }
});
```

I've tried rendering the SVGs using the `<object>` tag and referencing the `icon-name` to the React component, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert it to base64string first and then:

```
const iconName = '...';
const iconUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,[Your Base64 SVG String]';

registerIcons({
  icons: {
    [iconName]: {
      icon: iconUrl
    },
  },
});
```